# Find a value in an array and return a range result - GSheets

Tags: google-sheets

## Introduction

I am managing an event where I have volunteers to assign to some tasks over a few days.
Here is the link to a simplified version of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18_zRRmmT85pWc9rW8oS619YiTnxMzEEdJAS9Ayut4RQ/edit?usp=sharing

I need two views to gently handle the event:

1. Full volunteers list, with assigned tasks, in order to ensure that each of them are assigned a task and to inform them about their assigned task when they arrive at the event (refer to the `Volunteers` tab),
2. Tasks planning, with associated volunteers so I can keep track of the presence of the volunteers at the time they should be working (refer to the `Activity X` tabs)

## Problem

Now I will manually fill in the activity tabs with my volunteers and I need to have the `Assignation (expected)` column in `Volunteers` tab filled automatically (see the provided examples).

Hence the title: I need to find, in each `Activity` tab, the name of the assigned volunteers (value) and to retrieve which tasks with date and hour he has been assigned to (range result).

### Constrains

- The `Volunteers` tab already exists and is used for several purposes. Therefore it cannot be fully generated from the other tabs, only the `Assignation` column must be filled automatically,
- A single volunteer can have several assignation for the same activity (as long as it is not on the same time slot, so he will not appear twice in the same column),
- A single volunteer can have several assignations through several activities,
- Volunteers list in `Activity X` tabs would be hard to keep sorted as we fill the planning

## Approaches already tried

### `LOOKUP` family functions

[LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472): works only with sorted values, which is merely impossible to maintain by hand as we fill the tables.

[HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375): According to the documentation and admitting we cheat a bit in incorporating the *recap* in the `range`, it provides the expected result but only for the first row of the range:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2, act1_volunteers,ROWS(act1_volunteers), FALSE)
```

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472): Would not allow to retrieve the `summary` rows that I need to display on first tab.

### `HLOOKUP` in `ARRAYFORMULA`

I have hoped [that function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) would let me perform a kind of *for each row in range* action, but it provides the same result of the previous approach.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(A2, act1_volunteers,ROWS(act1_volunteers), FALSE))
```

### `INDEX` & `MATCH`

`MATCH` applies only on 1-dimension (either a row or a column, but not a range), and cannot be applied with `ARRAYFORMULA` to extend.

I have come to an end about my ideas, I was quite surprised to struggle to find such a function. I really feel the expected views are needed for the different managers of the event, but I could envisage to reform the tables if that could ease the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula below:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" / ", TRUE, FILTER(SPLIT('Activity 2'!$L$4, "|"), IF(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT('Activity 2'!$L$4, "|"), A2)=TRUE, "TRUE")))
```

Use this to match your name to the concatenated task list. You should paste this on the first cell and later drag it down the column.

A new sheet has been created and this is how the end result looks like:

[image: formula result]

#### Reference

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992);
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197);
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136);
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364);
- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the solution you provide does not fit my constrains, because you use the `Activity` tab to create the `Volunteers` tab, while in my case the `Volunteers` tab is a pre-existing reference.
What I expect is that only the column `Assignation` in the `Volunteers` tab will be filled, so we need somehow to check against the name in the first column to fill the assignation. I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: I have added a tab to your original sheet, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you.
So the solution would have been to use help cell to later use a filter on it. Nice!

Comment: No problem, I have edited the answer as such!